# Minecraft Update, change logs

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I recently got Minecraft for the WiiU and shortly after there was an update. I have searched the wiki as well as extensively googled and have not been able to find a change log or update notes etc.  .  All the sites link to a change log, but only for Xbox and PS4 and then say WiiU will be updated later. But I already have updated and don't know what was changed. I haven't played much at all prior to the update so I have no way to compare features either.

Answer (score 1):

While the minecraft wiki doesn't have too much detail on the changelog/updates at the time, you can find (at least the recent) patches/change logs on the minecraft forum.

Here's one link that I found on the minecraft forum - [Minecraft Updates/Change log - WiiU edition](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-wii-u-edition/mcwiiu-recent-upcoming-updates/2600838-minecraft-wiiu-edition-patch-change-logs)

Comment: Please post quotes in your answer from external link, because otherwise your answer would be worthless if the link died.